# Android: How to set onTouch event for activity?

Tags: android

I have an activity I want to finish when the activity is touched, how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Get a reference to the top level View in your layout and call .setOnTouchListener() on it passing an OnTouchListener with `finish();` in the onTouch() method.